# SiS chipset video problem

Tags: system-installation

Is there any release of Ubuntu that will install (and run) on an older computer with an SiS 651 integrated video chipset?  It's a know problem on 12.10.  It doesn't seem to be mentioned in any of the later release notes.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after some work:
The problem is SORT OF fixed in 14.10 (and possibly 13.xx).  I was able to install, but it will only use an 800X600 display.  I guess it's time to update my old hardware, sigh!

Answer (score 0):

According to the manpages for the [sis](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man4/sis.4.html) package.

> **SUPPORTED HARDWARE**
>
> The sis driver supports PCI, AGP and PCIe  video  cards  based  on  the following chipsets:

```
SiS5597/5598  SiS530/620  SiS6326/AGP/DVD  SiS300/305 SiS540 SiS630/730
SiS315/E/H/PRO   SiS550/551/552   SiS650/651/661/741   SiS330   (Xabre)
SiS760/761 XGI Volari V3/V5/V8 XGI Volari Z7
```

---

Besides bugs the 651 is supported and has been since at least [2008](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man4/sis.4.html). Though you might need to manually configure it.

---

It is hardware from Microsoft... if possible replacing it or adding another video card  might be a better option.

Comment: I wasn't able to get to this point with 12.04 - it wouldn't install.  I was able to install 14.04.  I'll check this out and also consider installing another video card.